# How to fix ExecuteQuery The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am working on small application which copies files from one sharepoint library to another library. I am using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect to copy file over to the other library. After copying file to destination any kind of 1st call to ExecuteQuery() throws exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

After exception the next call to ExecuteQuery() works perfectly. So only issue is with 1st call after copying file to destination.

This error occurs when copying PDF file to destination. It works with other type of documents e.g doc,xls,xml.

These files are copied on destination by creating sub directories and i already tried to refresh the root folders on destination.

I expect after copying file it should be able to run another query like to verify file is exist on destination and update some listitem attributes too, but it throwing an excption on any executequery() call.

```
public static bool CopyFile(string srcRelitivePath, string destRelitivePath)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(srcRelitivePath);
        sourceContext.Load(file);
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
        FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(sourceContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destinationContext, destRelitivePath, fileInfo.Stream, true);
        log.Debug("Uploaded file size is " + file.Length);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Debug(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set timeout for your `ClientContext` object ? Have you tried `ctx.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite;` ?

Comment: By setting that it will never timeout than

Comment: It's just an example, you can set to any amount you like.

Comment: I tried by setting timeout to infinite but that doesn’t solve problem. It is actually after executing specific number of queries say 3 and then timeout on every next

Comment: But you mentioned that it always happen after 1st call to the `ExecuteQuery`? Have you tried creating a new `ClientContext` every call instead of reusing ?

Comment: would that be necessary to create a new ClientContex. Would that effect any performance. Is this can be something with size of the fiel